# Namespace Prefixes in Wsdl (.net)

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx, xml-namespaces

Namespace prefixes in my wsdl are automatically generated: s1:, s2:, etc, how can i put a specific prefix for my namespaces?

Can't find it anywhere...

Do i have to override the xml serialization and add them by hand (how do i do that in .net webservices?)

(i mean in .net2.0 asmx, the guys who are going to use this webservice say they need that specific prefix instead of s1: and there is nothing i can do about that..)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean ASMX web services, or WCF? Also, which .NET version? Finally, please edit your question to say why you care about the prefix.

Comment: They should learn XML. In XML, prefixes don't matter.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean the prefixes in the WSDL itself, or in the XML you send? Can you post an example of what they don't like? I find it hard to imagine even bad old legacy code that would have trouble with different prefixes in a WSDL file.

Comment: Hi, could you please post an example showing what they feel is a problem? Also, they are mistaken if they feel that .NET 2.0 requires them to use particular prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have time for a full example, but see [XmlNamespaceDeclarationsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute.aspx). You can include a property in the class you're returning that will define the prefixes to use.

Comment: The XmsNamesapaceDeclerationAttribute works only for ASMX clients.